# Selenium webdriver doesn't open website - [fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pycharm

When i am trying to use selenium at pycharm it couldn't open websites.

I am using Debian, Pycharm 2017.1.5, selenium 3.0.1, geckodriver 0.19.1, Firefox 52.5.0 64bit.
I have tried solution with installing geckodriver for firefox and all the other fixes, but when i am trying to launch my app it holds when browser is launched and no website is load (empty, clean firefox).

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

My geckodriver.log:

```
1512819033857   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1512819033861   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:60859
1512819034970   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.6erCM69GHVqK"
1512819036141   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
[fresh] [error] probe_ppp_module, can't find libpepflashplayer.so
```

I have installed browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash and couldn't find what else is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on firefox flash player plugin.
 To get rid of this first Just do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
sudo mkdir -p /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/libpepflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
```

Then do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

Above will install pepper flash  to firefox.

Also Dont forget to set capabilities for mac geckodriver

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

 firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 firefox_profile.set_preference("webdriver.gecko.driver", "YourPathTo/geckodriver"")

 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile, capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```